# Stuck when trying to find a pointer with 'find out what writes to this address'

Tags: pointers, offset, cheat-engine

I started learning some game hacking recently.I have been watching videos and practicing.I tried to find a static entity in a game but i stuck at an address.When i start "what accesses this address" process i change a value in game and check the table.I see this

```
7FFF36815300 - 48 8B 04 C1   - mov rax,[rcx+rax*8]
```

What should i do to find the offset here ? Does rax*8 means multiply rax with 8 ? I couldn't find any address which has rax multiplied by 8 value.Looking for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`mov rax,[rcx+rax*8]`

This is how you index into an array in assembly.  There is a 80% change that's what is happening here.

rcx is the address of an array, rax is the index number or iterator, 8 is the size of each element in the array.

If it's an array of pointers, then this makes sense if the game is x64 because each pointer is 8 bytes in size.

Yes, rax*8 = multiply rax with 8.

I can't give any other advice without more context